# How to import a KMZ file and load data into correct columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kmz, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap

I have downloaded building heights attribute data from Ordnance Survey Mastermap. The format of the file is KMZ. After importing into QGIS, the data I need was displayed in one column named as "description" rather than individual columns as shown in the figure below. How can I split the description column into several columns to get the data I need?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common and unfortunate problem. In QGIS install the `KML Tools` Plugin and see if that imports the file correctly. I've found this only works sometimes.

Comment: You are right. The KML Tools Plugin has the option of Expand HTML description field that can solve this problem.